# NSData is nil After AsynchronousRequest In Swift

Tags: swift, http, request, nsdata

I am trying to add video data to the HTTP Request's body but sometimes video data is turning to nil but sometimes not. Is there anything to fix this situation?  When I delete the app from my app and after doing simulation again, nothing happened.

```
  @IBAction func post(sender: AnyObject) {

    let videodata = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL!)
    let headers = [
        "authorization": "Token \(userToken!)",
        "content-type": "/*/",
        "content-disposition": "attachment;filename=deneme.mp4",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    ]
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://molocate.elasticbeanstalk.com/video/upload/")!,
        cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData,
        timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.HTTPBody = videodata

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            //print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
            do {
                let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers)

                print("Result -> \(result)")
                let statue = result["result"] as! String
                if(statue == "success"){
                    let videoId = result["video_id"] as! String
                    let videoUrl = result["video_url"] as! String
                    print(videoUrl)
                    let json = [
                        "video_id": videoId,
                        "video_url": videoUrl,
                        "caption": "This city is awesome:)",
                        "category": "travel",
                        "tagged_users": [["username": "amertturker"]],
                        "location": [
                            [
                                "id": "mekmaekfmaıhjagej3ıo45j3kt348t3gkg",
                                "latitude": "35.342643",
                                "longitude": "32.345236",
                                "name": "Milas Merkez Kafasına göre herkes",
                                "address": "Milas aq"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]

                    let newheaders = [
                        "authorization": "Token \(userToken!)",
                        "content-type": "application/json",
                        "cache-control": "no-cache"
                    ]

                    do {

                        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: .PrettyPrinted)
                        print(NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

                        // create post request
                        let url = NSURL(string: "http://molocate.elasticbeanstalk.com/video/update/")!
                        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://molocate.elasticbeanstalk.com/video/update/")!,
                            cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                            timeoutInterval: 10.0)
                        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
                        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = newheaders
                        request.HTTPBody = jsonData


                        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in
                            print(response)

                            //print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                if error != nil{
                                    print("Error -> \(error)")

                                    return
                                }

                                do {

                                    let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)


                                    print("Result -> \(result)")



                                } catch {
                                    print("Error -> \(error)")
                                }
                            })
                        }

                        task.resume()




                    } catch {
                        print(error)


                    }



                } else{
                    //                        self.displayAlert("Hata", message: result["result"] as! String)
                    //                        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                    //                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    //                        self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                }




            } catch {
                print("Error -> \(error)")

            }
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()




    do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(videoPath!)  //.removeItemAtURL(fakeoutputFileURL!)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("siiiiil")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("finishUpdate", sender: self)

        }
    } catch _ {

    }
```

Comment: Does it catch the error? What does it print?

Comment: Yes it catch but it is just an issue about turn data into to the json because my server giving me an error that I do not have file in my request. I also checked the video data it is giving nil.

Comment: What line is it that gives you data = nil? Could you make it more clear, where in your code, the problem is occurring?

Comment: I didn t write in that code but in httpBuddy = videoData part

Answer (score 2):

Your calling the httprequest asynchronously and then trying to use the data on the calling thread.  It hasn't been populated until after the http request has returned which will occur at an undetermined future time.  Anything you want to do with videoData should be done inside the completion handler, otherwise you are in a race condition and it might be nil when you call it.

Comment: But when I delete the app and simulate again, I can upload video like 10 times then, it is again begin to give nil.

Comment: It's a race condition.  It will happen intermittently.

Comment: So a few things.  One, why are you doing everything on the main thread all the time?  Two, make video data a local variable within the async call.  I'm not sure where it's being initialized, but its possible your completion blocks are overwriting it while you are using it.

Comment: Ofcourse, it's also possible your data is actually nil

Comment: I am sorry, I am a newbie in Swift and I do not understand what do you mean with doing all these thing in main thread

Comment: You are queueing a bunch of blocks on the main thread with this:  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

Comment: how should I use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {? only one time in the completion handler or the only in the datataskrequest

Comment: I edited again delete app and simulate again it works 10 time with no problem and again it crush. Can it be related with the ram or temporary directory of the phone but again I checked the data storage but I can t see anything.

Comment: So you need to read up on how to write async code in ios properly, because your code has a lot of problems and you don't seem to understand what a lot of it is actually doing.

Comment: Actually I think I find out why is happening, overtime I applied this code my memory bar increases like 1.5 mb and when it hits to 20mb videoData starts to give nil value. Can it be related to memory management. I searched in the web about memory management but I am lost now. I do not know where should I look.

Comment: Its because of the poor threading you are doing above.  You are creating more and more blocks on the main thread, each one has video data in it.  Since you then are creating more main thread blocks from inside of the blocks you are initially creating, the video data is never cleaned up.

Comment: I edited my code again. I tried it like 15 times then there is no crush. Can this problem caused by the other portion of my code because in my app, I have build a table view cell with custom cell that include avasset that kept in nscache

Comment: Could you give look at this question? For my detailed explanation about my last comment.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807327/video-tableviewcell-cause-memory-error-in-swift